# Time Complexity Analysis in the following relation

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

Can the recurrence :

```
T(N)= SUM T(N-i)  //i=1 to N
```

be solved as:
    T(N)<= N*T(N-1)

```
which finally comes O(N^(N-1)) ?
```

By solving iteratively it comes:
    T(N)=N*(N-1)*T(N-2).... , T(N)=N*....(N-k+1)T(1), k=N-1.

so finally `O(N!)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `O` gives you an upper bound on the execution time, which means that if a certain algorithm, for example, is linear, then it is `O(n)`, but it is also `O(n^2)` and `O(n!)` and it is also `O` of any superlinear function.

Your inference is correct, however on both steps you overestimated your function complexity. The recurrent relation `T(N) = sum(T(N-i))` is  `O(2^N)` (and I suspect it is also `o(2^N)`). It is easy to show, since `2^n = sum(2^i) + 1` for `1 <= i <= n - 1`.

On your first step you used a higher bound, which is perfectly fine for the `O`. However, even with your bound of `T(N) <= N*T(N-1)` the complexity you ended up with is too high. `O(N!)`, which is less than what you estimated, also satisfies `T(N) <= N*T(N-1)`.

Comment: Yup , I made a mistake while mentally deducing it ! It should be like T(N)=N*(N-1)*T(N-2).... , T(N)=N*....(N-k+1)T(1), k=N-1. so finally O(N!)

Comment: But also, as I pointed out, it can be improved to `2^n`, which is the lowest complexity.